# How to change date format in Yii

Tags: php, yii2

Hello I am newbie in Yii. I am saving data in a table which saves created_at date. But I am getting different date format which is in integer like "`1462422044`" . I want to change it to `dd-mm-yyyy h:i:s`. **How to change this date format ?**

**My Master.php**

```
public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_at',
                ],
                'value' => function() {
            return time();
        },
            ],
            'user' => [
                'class' => UserBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_by', 'updated_by'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_by',
                ],
                'value' => function() {
            return \Yii::$app->user->id == '' ? 0 : \Yii::$app->user->id;
        },
            ],
        ];
    }
```

**My common/models/product.php**

```
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            BlameableBehavior::className(),
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['parent_id', 'created_by', 'updated_by'], 'integer'],
            [['category_name'], 'required'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['category_name'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: what is the datatype of field created_by in db?

Comment: I have datetime in db.

Comment: I am getting error : Incorrect date value: '1462422994' for column 'created_at' at row 1 because i have datetime datatype in db and the value is in integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data type is datetime in database then you have to store your value convert in to this format "Y-m-d H:i:s" you can do this like this way. and created_at field means you want to store current date and time. so try below code hope it's work fine. here i my model variable is $model you need to replace with your variable name. Below is the one way if you want to store current datetime.

```
$model->created_at= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Here is the second way you can convert form your variable. suppose you will get your value in `$currentDate` then you can do this like below code.

```
$model->created_at= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($currentDate));
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like below:

```
public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_at',
                ],
                'value' => function() {
            return date('d-m-Y h:i:s');
        },
            ],
            'user' => [
                'class' => UserBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_by', 'updated_by'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_by',
                ],
                'value' => function() {
            return \Yii::$app->user->id == '' ? 0 : \Yii::$app->user->id;
        },
            ],
        ];
    }
```

time() change to date('d-m-Y h:i:s').

Comment: Thanks but getting same result i am getting same error "Incorrect date value: '1462423477' for column 'created_at' at row 1"